# ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (30,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (9,30)

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

```
numeric_cols = ['temp', 'windchill', 'dewpoint', 'humidity', 'pressure', 'visibility', 'wind_speed', 'gust_speed', 'precip']
weather_list[numeric_cols] = weather_list[numeric_cols].apply(lambda x: re.sub('[^0-9]', '', str(x)))
weather_list[numeric_cols] = pd.to_numeric(weather_list[numeric_cols], errors='coerce')
weather_list[numeric_cols] = weather_list[numeric_cols] / 10
```

I'm trying to do a bit of cleaning of a data set but I'm getting the shape mismatch error. Going by the error, its saying I'm matching 30 columns, 0 rows with 9 columns, 30 rows... I've clearly done something wrong! I've used this method a few times before but never got error - anyone have any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong? Data pulled from html to pandas df 'weather_list'.

```
time     temp windchill dewpoint humidity  pressure visibility  \
0   12:53 AM  21.0 °F         -  19.0 °F      92%  30.47 in    10.0 mi   
1    1:53 AM  21.9 °F         -  19.9 °F      92%  30.48 in    10.0 mi   
2    2:53 AM  21.9 °F         -  19.0 °F      89%  30.50 in    10.0 mi   
3    3:53 AM  21.0 °F         -  19.0 °F      92%  30.50 in    10.0 mi   
4    4:53 AM  19.9 °F         -  18.0 °F      92%  30.51 in    10.0 mi   
5    5:53 AM  21.0 °F         -  18.0 °F      88%  30.51 in    10.0 mi   


   wind_direction wind_speed gust_speed  precip  events conditions  
0            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear  
1            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear  
2            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear  
3            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear  
4            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear  
5            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you post a sample of the weather_list dataframe?

Comment: time     temp windchill dewpoint humidity  pressure visibility  \
0   12:53 AM  21.0 °F         -  19.0 °F      92%  30.47 in    10.0 mi   
1    1:53 AM  21.9 °F         -  19.9 °F      92%  30.48 in    10.0 mi   
2    2:53 AM  21.9 °F         -  19.0 °F      89%  30.50 in    10.0 mi   
  

   wind_direction wind_speed gust_speed  precip  events conditions  
0            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear  
1            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear  
2            Calm       Calm          -     NaN     NaN      Clear ---- see above @AshishAcharya

Comment: @DavidBlack, It wil be great if you can  edit the question rather than commenting a bits of your question.

Comment: you need to use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) instead of `apply`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use applymap to apply a function to multiple columns. Please make the following changes to your code.

```
## using applymap here
weather_list[numeric_cols] = weather_list[numeric_cols].applymap(lambda x: re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', str(x)))

## now we pass series to pd.to_numeric instead of data frame
weather_list[numeric_cols] = weather_list[numeric_cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

weather_list[numeric_cols] = weather_list[numeric_cols] / 10
```